# De Morgans Law Negation Simplification

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a statement with quantifiers, I have been asked to find the negation of this statement but am really struggling with applying De Morgans Law.

The statement is

```
∀x prime(x) -> (odd(x) V (x = 2))
```

From my understanding by applying De Morgans law you get

```
∃x prime(x) ∧ (¬odd(x) ∧ (x ≠ 2))
```

The answers however, suggests that the answer is

```
∃x ¬prime(x) ∧ (¬odd(x) ∧ (x ≠ 2))
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, their answer is wrong. As a check, since the original statement is true, its negation should be false, whereas their answer is true.

Comment: Thank you, I just forgot the (x) off the prime.